# Cannot import txt file using Oracle SQL developer

Tags: oracle, import, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I'm trying to import data from a.txt file into an Oracle database for that I'm using Oracle sql developper. But I got this message (sorry it's in french). I'm connected with the DBA profile.

[image]

Question : how can i fix this ?

Comment: "There are no readers registered for the txt type" - what version of SQL Developer are you using? This is referred to in old Oracle community threads but seems to work OK in the current version. If you can't upgrade you could just change the suffix to say .csv - presumably the data in the file is delimitued?

Comment: What Alex said - upgrade. If you can't, rename the file or copy it over as a .tsv file. If it's comma delimited, rename it to .csv. But latest version is happy to work with .txt files - as long as there is a delimiter character/string in there, somewhere.

Comment: Thank you guys ! I choose the renaming process.

Comment: @AlexPoole I'm using Version  3.2.20.10

Comment: @AtimeneNazim I'm glad that worked, please upgrade when you can. Your software is 6 years old.